# Civilization 5 Hotseat with Diplomatic Victory

Tags: civilization-5

I play Hotseat with my brother and we have this problem.
if the 2nd player in turn wins the diplomatic victory the game ends with defeat screen for the first player and the 2nd player doesnt get his victory score. And we have some like competition who will do the biggest victory score at our leaderboard.. is anyway that this can be fixed? and instead the game ends with defeat on defeated players turn to end with victory on the victorious player turn?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic. Bug reports should be sent to the game developer.

Comment: hmm so this is a bug and nothing can be done? is not something we miss?